# Problem of creating function handle from the result of symbolic differentiation

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative

Suppose I have a simple function handle defined as

```
Eq.1    F = @(t,A) A(1) + A(2)*t + A(3)*t^2;
```

And I'd like to define another function handle from the differentiation of `F`, such as

```
Eq.2:  dF = @(t,A) diff( F(t,A), t );
```

But, it seems forbidden to evaluate `dF` at some specific `t`, such as `dF(0,A)`, and an error occurs as

> "The second argument must either be variables or a variable"

Then I tried to use the expression shown below:

```
Eq.3   dF(t,A) = diff( F(t,A), t );
```

This way, it allows direct evaluation at `t`=0

However, it must be in the form of `dF( 0, A(1), A(2), A(3) )` to evaluate Eq.3 rather than `dF(0,A)`

My question is:

Is there a simpler way to make this direct evaluation work using the direct form `dF(0,A)` rather than `dF(0, A(1), ... )`

To save the effort of typing, ony-by-one, `A(...)` in `dF( 0, A(1), A(2), ..., A(100) )`, suppose there are 100 parameters

PS:
Without using `matlabFunction`

---

The testing codes are as follows:

```
syms t A a0 a1 a2

A = [a0,a1,a2];

F = @(t,A) A(1) + A(2)*t + A(3)*t^2;

dF1      =          @(t,A) diff( F(t,A), t );

dF2(t,A) =                 diff( F(t,A), t );                   % Same as using symfun

dF3      = matlabFunction( diff( F(t,A), t ), 'Vars', {t,A} );
```

Now, type in the command window,

```
>> dF1(t,A)
>> ans = a1 + 2*a2*t

>> dF1(0,A)
>> ans = a0               % This is wrong

>> dF3(t,A)
>> ans = a1 + 2*a2*t

>> dF3(0,A)
>> ans = a1               % This is correct

>> dF2(t,A)
   Error using symfun/subsref (line 141)
   Symbolic function expected 4 inputs and received 2.

>> dF2(t,a0,a1,a2)
>> ans = a1 + 2*a2*t

>> dF2(0,a0,a1,a2)
>> ans = a1               % This is correct
```

It is obvious that only `dF2` is a symbolic function.
However, the form of inputs seems not so friendly.

The `matlabFunction` runs much slower than `symfun`, and `@(x,A) diff(...)` can't admit numerical results. This is why I want to use `symfun` to define a function that has too many parameters. Yet the form of inputs of symbolic function seems not so direct nor friendly.

Comment: There are two different `diff` functions. Symbolic differentiation requires calling with a `syms` argument so that the `diff` function from the Symbic Toolbox is called. When called with a numeric input, it computes the difference between subsequent elements in the array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry, I didn't make it clear. Eq.3 is usable, but I have to type dF( 1.0, A(1), A(2), ... )  to get the result, rather than dF( 1.0, A ) directly. My question is that it is possible to avoid typing all the elements of A, without using matlabFunction ( costing too much time )

Comment: I don’t understand what you are saying, and don’t see why you would have to type all elements of A. Could you please [edit] your post to include some actual code? It will make it much, much easier to talk about the problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've added some testing codes. I'm using MATLAB 2015b, and I don't know if the latest version shows similar problem. I just want to define a symbolic function that has many parameters in an efficient way, and to make it easier to evaluate the function with too many inputs. Thank you very much for teaching me!

Comment: I've re-written my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is answered [over at MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/365462-how-to-define-a-symbolic-function-that-receives-a-vector). In short: this cannot be done.
You cannot create a symbolic function that uses an array as input:

> This all reflects a fundamental internal limitation in the symbolic engine: the very insides of the symbolic engine have no provision for describing or operating on an "array" whose contents will be filled in later.

The linked post goes in great detail explaining why and how the symbolic engine in MATLAB works. I recommend that you read it.

---

Your code shows some misconceptions around symbolic functions and anonymous functions. When you do

```
F = @(t,A) A(1) + A(2)*t + A(3)*t^2;
```

you are creating a function handle to an anonymous function. It is completely unrelated to the symbolic variables `t` and `A`, and it is not a symbolic function. Here, `t` and `A` are just the input arguments, and can be filled in by anything.

Next,

```
dF1 = @(t,A) diff( F(t,A), t );
```

creates another function handle to an anonymous function, this time the function will evaluate `x=F(t,A)`, then call `diff(x,t)`, where `diff` is [the normal function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), not the one in the symbolic toolbox. It computes the difference between subsequent array elements, `t` times.

To create a symbolic function, you can do:

```matlab
clear
syms t
A = sym('a', [1,3]);        % A = [a1, a2, a3]
F = symfun(A(1) + A(2)*t + A(3)*t^2, [t, A]);
dF = diff(F, t);
dF(0, A(1), A(2), A(3))     % returns a2
```

However, this creates a symbolic function where each of the elements of `A` is a separate input argument, which is not what you want. There is no way around this, except, as suggested in an answer to the post I linked at the top, to create an anonymous function that evaluates your symbolic expression:

```matlab
clear
syms t
A = sym('a', [1,3]);
F = symfun(A(1) + A(2)*t + A(3)*t^2, [t, A]);
dF_sym = diff(F, t);
dF = @(t,A)dF_sym(t, A(1), A(2), A(3));
dF(0, A)                    % returns a2
```

---

PS: Note that the `symfun` call above is identical to:

```matlab
clear
syms t F(t,a1,a2,a3)
F(t,a1,a2,a3) = a1 + a2*t + a3*t^2;
```

and this is how you would normally create a symbolic function. I used `symfun` above to be able to use `A` instead of `a1`, `a2` and `a3`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  'dF = @(t,A)dF_sym(t, A(1), A(2), A(3))'  solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have just mixed up a few things.
You [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) definitions are fine, but I don't think that they represent your intended use.

The function [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) calculates the *difference in a vector* or does this n-times The second argument specifies the latter:

> Y = diff(X,n) calculates the nth difference by applying the diff(X)
> operator recursively n times. In practice, this means diff(X,2) is the
> same as diff(diff(X)).

So it is obvious that `diff(...,0)` raises an error ("calculate the 0th difference of something").
I can't help thinking that this is not what you want (because there wouldn't be a point in using `t` in the original function `F` ...). I assume that `t` is a time (vector)

Perhaps this suits more your problem:

```matlab
F = @(t,A) A(:,1) + A(:,2).*t + A(:,3).*t.^2; % vector-wise
dF = @(t,A) diff(F(t,A),[],1)./diff(t,[],1); % row-wise difference
```

So you can do

```matlab
t = (1:10).'; % 10 rows = 10 time steps
A = rand(length(t),3);

% call dF: approximating the 1st derivative as finite difference (row-wise)
dF(t,A)
```

PS: those are no *symbolic* functions but just *anonymous function handles*, i.e. pointers to functions (there is a separate *Symbolic Math Toolbox* and to get a symbolic math function to a function handle, you can use the [`matlabFunction`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) function)

Comment: Upvote for the explanation of the problem. The proposed solution is not so good though. It requires F to accept array inputs, and it doesn’t produce a very precise estimate of the derivative (depending on the steepness of the function of course).